# Installing Torch and running install.sh - luajit: not enough memory

Tags: torch, luajit

I am trying to install Torch like described [here](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html). That means I'm trying to run these commands :

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
./install.sh
```

If I do so, the call of `./install.sh` fails with this error:

```
...
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/myUser/torch/pkg/torch/build
[  5%] Building C object lib/luaT/CMakeFiles/luaT.dir/luaT.c.o
[  5%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THHalf.c.o
[  7%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THGeneral.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THFile.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THLapack.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THAllocator.c.o
[ 17%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THSize.c.o
[ 20%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THStorage.c.o
[ 23%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THRandom.c.o
[ 28%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THMemoryFile.c.o
[ 25%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THTensor.c.o
[ 30%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THBlas.c.o
[ 33%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THLogAdd.c.o
[ 35%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THDiskFile.c.o
[ 38%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THAtomic.c.o
[ 41%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/THVector.c.o
[ 43%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/generic/simd/convolve.c.o
[ 46%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/generic/simd/convolve5x5_sse.c.o
[ 48%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/vector/AVX2.c.o
[ 51%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/generic/simd/convolve5x5_avx.c.o
[ 53%] Building C object lib/TH/CMakeFiles/TH.dir/vector/AVX.c.o
[ 56%] Linking C shared library libluaT.so
[ 56%] Built target luaT
[ 58%] Linking C shared library libTH.so
[ 58%] Built target TH
[ 64%] Generating random.c
[ 64%] Generating TensorMath.c
/home/myUser/torch/install/bin/luajit: not enough memory
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/torch.dir/build.make:74: TensorMath.c] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'TensorMath.c'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:133: CMakeFiles/torch.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

Attempting to run it again yielded a slightly different error message:

```
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/myUser/torch/pkg/torch/build
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target luaT
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target TH
[  5%] Built target luaT
[ 58%] Built target TH
[ 61%] Generating TensorMath.c
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (not enough memory)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/torch.dir/build.make:74: TensorMath.c] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:133: CMakeFiles/torch.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: So, what is your RAM size?

Comment: @ESkri 16 gigabyte

Comment: Better ask the project authors.

Comment: @ESkri ok, thank you, could you tell me where is the appropriate place to do that?

Comment: may be GitHub ?